# Draw a black point at a specific position in an image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a function that gets me the coordinates of the position of an image when you click on it. What I want to achieve is that when I click on the image draw a point in that same position as shown in the image:

[image]

this is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://t1.up.ltmcdn.com/es/images/2/6/6/img_organos_internos_del_cuerpo_humano_lista_completa_1662_600.jpg" height="500" width="500" alt="dragon">


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("click", function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        alert("X Coordinate: " + x + " Y Coordinate: " + y);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You could use a `position:relative;` container, and and use `position:absolute;` on the children. Of course, you make an Element for your dot. You never did that. By the way, jQuery has `jQueryElement.top()` and `jQueryElement.left()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could superimpose a `<canvas>` element on top of the image. But if dots are the only goal, then that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append an absolutely positioned element to the coordinates:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://t1.up.ltmcdn.com/es/images/2/6/6/img_organos_internos_del_cuerpo_humano_lista_completa_1662_600.jpg" height="500" width="500" alt="dragon">


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    const size = 4;
    $("img").on("click", function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $(this).parent().append(`<div style="width: ${size}px; height: ${size}px; background: black; position: absolute; top: ${y + size}px; left: ${x + size}px; border-radius: ${size}px"/>`); 
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use raw JavaScript. I don't have time to fully explain right now, but may later. Good Luck!

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// magic under here
const stage = I('stage'), human = I('human'), dot = M('div'), dotStyle = dot.style;
dot.id = 'dot';
let move = false;
function moveDot(e){
  if(move === true){
    let left = e.clientX, top = e.clientY;
    if(!stage.contains(dot))stage.appendChild(dot);
    dotStyle.left = left+'px'; dotStyle.top = top+'px';
  }
}
if(mobile){
  human.ontouchstart = (e)=>{
    move = true; moveDot(e);
  }
  human.ontouchmove = moveDot;
  human.ontouchend = ()=>{
    move = false;
  }
}
else{
  human.onmousedown = e=>{
    move = true; e.preventDefault(); moveDot(e);
    
  }
  human.onmousemove = moveDot;
  human.onmouseup = ()=>{
    move = false;
  }
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; background:#ccc;
}
.main,#stage{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#stage{
  position:relative; height:100%;
}
#stage>*{
  position:absolute;
}
#human{
  height:100%; margin:auto; top:0; right:0; bottom;0; left:0;
}
#dot{
  border:1px solid #009; border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='stage'>
      <img id='human' src='https://t1.up.ltmcdn.com/es/images/2/6/6/img_organos_internos_del_cuerpo_humano_lista_completa_1662_600.jpg' alt='dragon' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```